# HTML flexbox going off the screen when minimised

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am currently developing a website and I am trying to make it responsive. When I try to decrease the screen size, the blocks are going towards the right side of the screen rather than shrinking.

I tried using flex-wrap: wrap and flex-shrink:0; and also setting the width and height to auto which didn't work

Comment: Please include a [mre]

Comment: https://codepen.io/strike34/pen/XWyqRrM

Comment: Please include the code in the question as text (rather than a link or image) If that link changes or breaks, this question will no longer be useful to future viewers. You can use the "snippet" tool to produce a working example just like codepen.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you have the footer set to: width: 1280px;
This means that any values inside the footer will take up 1280px of space, so set this to max-width: 100%;

You also have certain elements in your page set to specific px too.
With the elements inside set to specific px, including the gaps, you should consider rethinking how many pixels these will take up, as you will see the page still overflows when using a max-width on the footer.

My recommendation is to learn Media queries, rem, em and % to make pages responsive, flexbox wrap and flexbox shrink is a great help but that isn't how you usually get responsive designs.

Answer (score 0):

1. Setting specific width on your elements like [Becki wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76713555/2754358) prevents your elements from getting an auto width.
2. Setting `flex` or `flex-wrap` on everything is generally the wrong approach in these cases. The best thing is to get rid of as much CSS as you can, start small and work your way up (see example below). Most of the times you don't need as much HTML wrappers and stuff as you think either.

If you really need all that CSS in your project more analysis is needed to figure out *why* your layout isn't working.

Here is a working, responsive example with both flex and grid approaches:

```css
.input {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 20px;
}
#subscribe {
  height: 54px;
  border-radius: 32px;
  background: #5f9cff;
}
#emailadr {
  flex:  1;
  display: flex;
  height: 54px;
  min-width: 200px;
  padding-inline: 11px;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
}

.itemli {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="container container-10">
    <div class="firstblock">
      <h1>Logo</h1>
      <div class="innerblock">
        <div class="updates">
          <p>Updates right to your invox</p>
          <div class="input">
            <input type="text" id="emailadr" placeholder="Email adress">

            <button type="button" id="subscribe" class="btn btn-primary">Secondary</button>

          </div>

        </div>

        <ul class="copyright">
          <li>©</li>
          <li>Company2022</li>
          <li>Privacy Policy</li>
          <li>Terms of use</li>
        </ul>

      </div>

    </div>

    <div class=" secondblock">
      <div class="itemli">
        <ul class="list list-1">
          <li style="">Our story</li>
          <li>FAQ</li>
          <li>Contact</li>

        </ul>
        <ul class="list list-2">
          <li>Title</li>
          <li>Item</li>
          <li>Item</li>
          <li>Item</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="list list-3">
          <li>Title</li>
          <li>Item</li>
          <li>Item</li>
          <li>Item</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="socials">
        <img src="Ellipse 19.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="Ellipse.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="Facebook.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="Ellipse 19.jpg" alt="">
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</footer>
```